# Splice a string based on certain characters

Tags: python, string, splice

I'm looking for a way to examine only certain characters within a string. For example:

```
#Given the string
s= '((hello+world))'
s[1:')'] #This obviously doesn't work because you can only splice a string using ints
```

Basically I want the program to start at the second occurence of `(` and then from there splice until it hits the first occurence of `)`. So then maybe from there I can return it to another fucntion or whatever. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows: (assuming you want the innermost parenthesis)

`s[s.rfind("("):s.find(")")+1]` if you want "(hello+world)"

`s[s.rfind("(")+1:s.find(")")]` if you want "hello+world"

Comment: Hmm I think this may work, I'm actually doing regexes and I'm function to determine if an input that's a string is a valid regex. I have another question as well but I don't think it warrants another post

Comment: So using that `find()` function, I can return the index of a certain character in a string right?

Comment: Also why did you use `rfind()` instead of `find()`?

Comment: @Amon, Yes. That is what `find` does. It finds the first occurrence of the specified string. `rfind` returns the highest index of the given search term. Basically, it gives the rightmost occurence of the string you are searching for. In this case, you want the rightmost occurence of "(" to get the deepest level of parenthesis.

Comment: I see,  great thanks. So `find()` returns the leftmost occurence then right? Putting it that way makes it easier to understand it's functionality.

Comment: @Amon, Yes `find()` starts searching from left and `rfind()` essentially searches from the right

Comment: Sorry one more question, is there a way to return the indexes of all the occurrences of a certain character?

Comment: @Amon, `return [x for x in range(len(string)) if string[x]==char]`. This returns a list of indices

Answer (score 1):

You can [strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) parenthesis (if, in your case, they always appear at the beginning and the end of the string):

```
>>> s= '((hello+world))'
>>> s.strip('()')
'hello+world'
```

Another option is to use regular expression to extract what is inside the double parenthesis:

```
>>> re.match('\(\((.*?)\)\)', s).group(1)
'hello+world'
```